# Blocking thread from entering method

Tags: c#, multithreading

Example code:

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject ();

public void FunA () // accessed from thread 1 (when user click a button)
{
    myObject = null;
    // do some stuff
    myObject = new MyObject ( someNewValues );
}

public void FunB () // accessed from thread 2 (calling using timer or smth.)
{
    int x = myObject.ReadX ();
}
```

In most cases it works OK, but when FunA will make myObject null and in same time FunB will access it, application will crash.

Question: How to do that, when thread 1 will access FunA, thread 2 cannot enter FunB?

**Update:** I tried locks before, but the problem is FunB is calling event to thread 1 (GUI) (guiForm.Invoke) and thread 1 will stuck before FunA { lock... }.

Comment: Can you confirm whether you want to wait for `FunA` to finish *then* enter or do you want to simply skip `FunB` completely?

Comment: Is it intended for FunA() to be called **multiple** times to create a new instance of myObject each time or is it intended to only call FunA() to be called **once** for initialization and after that to use FunB() to always work with the same myObject instance?

Comment: I call FunA when user changes cursor position of audio stream. When I change cursor position I need to re-initialize my PhaseVocoder class. So FunA is called many times. FunB is always fetching data from PhaseVocoder each 250ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can lock `myObject` so that only the current thread can use it.

```
public void FunA () // accessed from thread 1 (when user click a button)
{
  lock(myObject)
    {
       myObject = null;
       // do some stuff
       myObject = new MyObject ( someNewValues );
    }
}
```

This will prevent `FunB` from accessing `myObject` until it has been released by the lock.

**Update**

As pointed out in the comments, it's probably not a good idea to modify the object that you have a lock on. In this case you can simply have an object that you lock and an object that you modify such that:

```
var lockObj = new object();
var myObject = new MyObject();


public void FunA () // accessed from thread 1 (when user click a button)
{
  lock(lockObj)
    {
       myObject = null;
       // do some stuff
       myObject = new MyObject ( someNewValues );
    }
}

public void FunB () // accessed from thread 2 (calling using timer or smth.)
{
    lock(lockObj)
    {
       int x = myObject.ReadX ();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not certain it's wise to modify the object you're locking on.

Comment: +1 that works, but just to make it clear: this only ensures you can't call FunA and FunB at the same time **within an instance of the object containing them** -> consider making the lock *static readonly* otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Just issue a lock on a lock object, like this:

```
static object lockObject = new Object();
MyObject myObject = new MyObject (); 

public void FunA () // accessed from thread 1 (when user click a button) 
{ 
    lock (lockObject)
    {
        myObject = null; 
        // do some stuff 
        myObject = new MyObject ( someNewValues ); 
    }
} 

public void FunB () // accessed from thread 2 (calling using timer or smth.) 
{ 
    lock (lockObject)
    {
        int x = myObject.ReadX (); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative approach, perhaps use an [EventWaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.aspx) like an [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.AutoResetEvent.aspx), so thread 2 blocks until thread 1 has set the thread synchronisation object.

Example code:

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject ();
private static EventWaitHandle WaitHandle_m = new AutoResetEvent(false);

public void FunA () // accessed from thread 1 (when user click a button)
{   
    myObject = null;
    // do some stuff
    myObject = new MyObject ( someNewValues );
    WaitHandle_m.Set();
}

public void FunB () // accessed from thread 2 (calling using timer or smth.)
{
    if (!WaitHandle_m.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)))
    {
        // whoops.
    }
    else
    {
        int x = myObject.ReadX ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic synchronization problem. A mutex will be useful. View the samples from MSDN.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx

Should be something like this

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject ();
Mutex mutex = new Mutex();

public void FunA ()
{
    mutex.WaitOne();
    myObject = null;
    // do some stuff
    myObject = new MyObject ( someNewValues );
    mutex.ReleaseMutex();
}

public void FunB ()
{
    mutex.WaitOne();
    int x = myObject.ReadX ();
    mutex.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

Comment: Damn, a Mutex just for that? you're not kidding around =o

Comment: What else are mutexes useful for, if not controlling resource usage across threads and processes ;)????

Comment: For example, to ensure only one instance of a process is running. A lock is enough here.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Lazy class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx). This ensures that multithreaed access to the concrete object **is automatically handled**.

You can control **how** the simultaneous access is handled by defining the [LazyThreadSafetyMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.lazythreadsafetymode.aspx) in the constructor.